# Conda: packages are already installed by pip but not shown in conda list

Tags: python, pip, conda

I use pip install packages in a conda environment.

```
pip install pygame
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.9.4)
```

where the current directory is `/Users/aptx4869`. However, when I type `conda list`, there is nothing in the current environment. What's wrong with it? Here's the directory where the environment is at

```
/Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/rl
```

### Update

I delete the `pygame` in the root environment and run `pip install pygame` in the `rl` conda environment, I receive another message. But `pygame` still doesn't show in `conda list`

```
 pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/19/57bf1e9c72be4f7afc1add56cc717b7f7fe8ef1b6b5fb58f031a06401d0f/pygame-1.9.4-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.4
(rl)
```

Notice `(rl)` in the end, this `pip` command still installs `pygame` in the root environment

Comment: can you import it using the conda's python?

Comment: @user2906838 I'm sorry. How to import it?

Comment: run `python` in the terminal and do `import pygame`, if there is no error, then you've your package all fine. Make sure the `python` inside the terminal is pointing to the conda's distribution. You can varify that by printing `sys.path`.

Comment: @user2906838. I cannot import `pygame` in the current environment. BTW, I've installed this package in another environment before, is this the reason why this happened?

Comment: if you're using virtual environment, then yes, installing one package in one Venv won't let you have the same package in another Venv.

Comment: @user2906838 Hi, I don't understand it yet. I have several environments which contain packages like `six`, `numpy`, `tensorflow`, and etc. why I cannot have `pygame` in two environments?

Comment: Yes, you can have, you need to install pygame in all environments, say you have two Venv in which you need pygame or any other package, you have to install it on both Venv. Installing in one virtual environment won't let you acess that package in another Venv, that's what I meant.

Comment: I did call `pip install pygame` in my `rl` environment, but pygame didn't shown in `conda list`. I've updated the question for the new message I received after call `pip install pygame`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simply because I didn't install python and pip in the `dl` environment, and conda implicitly uses python and pip in the root environment as I command `pip install ...`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you installed the `pygame` package into the root environment when you run `pip install pygame` the first time. So make sure that you have activated the environment into which you want to install packages and then use `pip` to install the packages. Doing this, you should see the packages in the list of `conda list` command. Also, you must run the `conda list` command in the same environment  where you run `pip install`.

Comment: Thx for answering. I've noticed that `pygame` was installed in the root environment. However after I delete the `pygame` in the root environment and switch to `rl` environment, I run `pip install pygame`, which still installs `pygame` in the root environment. See the **update** in the question, there's `(rl)` at the end

Answer (score 0):

After facing the same problem, here is the solution that worked for me:
From a separate terminal (not VSCode integrated terminal), with my virtual environment active:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

It is important not simply call pip (or pip3) directly, and it apparently mattered to not do it from VSCode integrated terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a few times with different packages, and 9 times out of 10 it's an issue wit managing multiple conda environments.

You can have multiple conda environments active at the same time. If you activate one environment from another environment, it doesn't necessarily close the first environment. So, say that you create `myenv`:

```
(base)$ conda create myenv
(base)$ conda activate myenv
(myenv)$
```

You work in that environment for a bit, run into some problems, and then realize that it's easier to start another environment from scratch. If you do

```
(myenv)$ conda create myenv2
(myenv)$ conda activate myenv2
(myenv2)$
```

You have activated `myenv2`. However, you haven't explicitly closed `myenv`. You can see this when you deactivate `myenv2`

```
(myenv2)$ conda deactivate
(myenv)$
```

I have't researched this behavior too deeply, but I know that it can create issues with pip installs within conda. Try deactivating your conda environments to base and then activating only the environment of interest. It fixed the problem for me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following steps to fix the issue :

```
 1. conda env remove -n <ENV_NAME> // delete the current environment.
 2. conda create -n <ENV_NAME> python=3.10 // recreate it using python version.
 3. conda activate <ENV_NAME>
 4. pip freeze --user > packages.txt // get the packages for the user
 5. pip uninstall -r packages.txt // uninstall 
 6. pip install -r packages.txt // install
```